# Pausing the "run" method in the worker thread

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython, python-multithreading

I have a background thread in my wxPython application to keep the GUI responsive. 
There's a while(true) loop in the "run" method of my background thread but I also have other methods that I sometimes call from the GUI thread. Is there anyway to stop the run method while I get into another method of the background thread?

Comment: Why? If you call the methods from the UI functions, they will run in the context of the UI thread, but can still access variables and stuff inside the worker thread. You might have to protect those variables with e.g. semaphore though.

Comment: Sorry I'm very new to Python so I am not sure what you mean. I want to call worker threads methods (which is already in a while loop in run its run method) from the GUI methods.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have some code like this:

```
import threading
import time

class MyWorkerThread(threading.Thread):
    def run():
        while True:
            # Do some important stuff here
            foo()
            time.sleep(0.5)

    def foo():
        # Do something important here too
        pass

class SomeRandomButton:
    def __init__(worker_thread):
        self.worker_thread = worker_thread

    # Function called when button is clicked
    def on_button_clicked():
        self.worker_thread.foo();

my_worker_thread = MyWorkerThread()
my_button = SomeRandomButton(my_worker_thread)

# Start thread
my_worker_thread.run()

# Initialize the GUI system (creating controls etc.)

# Start GUI system
GUISystem.run()
```

The code above doesn't actually do anything, and wont even run, but I will use it to show that a function in a thread object (`MyWorkerThread.foo`) doesn't *have* to be called from that specific thread, it can be called from *any* thread.

You may want to read more about multithreading, and maybe about [semaphores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29) to protect data from being accessed by multiple thread simultaneous.

Comment: Thanks. So when I call foo from SomeRandomButton, will it run on the MyWorkerThread thread or the thread where the button belongs to?

Comment: @Milad It will run in the thread the button belongs to, which is why you may have to use semaphores to protect data.

Comment: I see! So does this mean I have to define a separate thread for every action in my GUI to keep it responsive?

Comment: @Milad No, The GUI system will handle that. Only if you have long-running events, like downloading a file or some heavy number-crunching, will you have to create a new thread for that.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like

```
while(alive):
  while(not stopped):
     """
        thread body

     """
```

and somewhere else you will be able to pause thread with

```
stopped=True
```

and than use

```
stopped = True
alive = False
```

to quit thread